# Как правильно передать IP в базу данных с postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql

У меня есть скрипт со строкой, в которой ip. В принципе, я могу передать его как строку, но я думаю, что это не правильно. Как это сделать правильно и какой типа для ip указывать при создании таблицы?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Используйте `cidr` или `inet`.

Преимущество их в том, что вы можете сразу использовать различные
операции непосредственно над ними:

Например:

```
SELECT '192.168.1.19'::inet << '192.168.1.0/24'::cidr;
```

Подробнее об этих типах данных:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-net-types.html (англ.)

Как использовать в Python эти типы?
Нужно непосредственно в запросе сконвертировать строку в соответствующий тип:

Например:

```
>>> psycopg2.extras.register_inet()
<psycopg2._psycopg.type object at 0x...>

>>> cur.mogrify("SELECT %s", (Inet('127.0.0.1/32'),))
"SELECT E'127.0.0.1/32'::inet"

>>> cur.execute("SELECT '192.168.0.1/24'::inet")
>>> cur.fetchone()[0].addr
'192.168.0.1/24'
```